# What is the opposite of block letters?

Tags: antonyms

According to wiki, the definition of block letter is as follows

Block letters (known as printscript, manuscript, print writing or ball and stick in academics) are a sans-serif (or "gothic") style of writing Latin script in which the letters are individual glyphs, with no joining. In English-speaking countries, children are often first taught to write in block letters, and later may advance to cursive (joined) writing. Other countries (Poland, Italy, Austria, Germany, France, etc.) focus on cursive writing from the first grade.

At first, I think the opposite of block letter is cursive letter (let's assume the opposite of block letter is the most common letter among non-block letter). But what if I print some documents using cursive font. Then are the printed letters of cursive font block letters? So what is the actual opposite of block letters?

Comment: Cursive letters vs block letters

Answer (score 1):

The terms we use in relation to screen and printed fonts do tend to be different to those in handwriting.

Most commonly, we use 'script' for cursive although, just to confuse things 'handwriting' is often used

For example, Google breaks the font types down into Serif, Sans-serif, Display, Handwriting and Monospaced